# NOAA's GIS Polygons - How to use them?

Tags: gis, noaa

NOAA gives a Polygon area for plotting shapes on a map.  The only thing I can find in google maps is to use a lat/lon to create a shape.

You can view the warnings here with their polygons:
http://www.nws.noaa.gov/regsci/gis/last10.html

Can somebody please tell me what these 4 digit numbers represent and if it's possible to convert them to a latitude / longitude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numbers are hundredths of degrees.  A 4-digit number is latitude, so for instance 3503 represents 35.03 degrees North latitude.  A 5-digit number is longitude, so 10581 would be 105.81 degrees West longitude.